# Get different LIMIT on each group on postgresql rank

Tags: postgresql, row-number, partition-by

To get 2 rows from each group I can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with condition `<= 2` at last but my question is what If I want to get different limits on each group e.g 3 rows for section_id 1, 1 rows for 2 and 1 rows for 3?

Given the following table:

```
db=# SELECT * FROM xxx;
 id | section_id | name
----+------------+------
  1 |          1 | A
  2 |          1 | B
  3 |          1 | C
  4 |          1 | D
  5 |          2 | E
  6 |          2 | F
  7 |          3 | G
  8 |          2 | H
(8 rows)
```

I get the first 2 rows (ordered by **name**) for each **section_id**, i.e. a result similar to:

```
 id | section_id | name
----+------------+------
  1 |          1 | A
  2 |          1 | B
  5 |          2 | E
  6 |          2 | F
  7 |          3 | G
(5 rows)
```

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section_id ORDER BY name) AS r,
    t.*
  FROM
    xxx t) x
WHERE
  x.r <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table to contain the section limits, then join. The big advantage being that as new sections are required or limits change maintenance is reduced to a single table update and comes at very little cost. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ba92ec1dc4f8450948b32a85e4f2fe33).

```
select s.section_id, s.name  
  from (select section_id, name 
             , row_number() over (partition by section_id order by name) rn
          from sections
       )  s 
  left join section_limits sl on (sl.section_id = s.section_id) 
where 
  s.rn <= coalesce(sl.limit_to,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fix up your `where` clause:

```
with numbered as (
  select row_number() over (partition by section_id
                                order by name) as r,
         t.*
    from xxx t
)
select *
  from numbered
 where (section_id = 1 and r <= 3)
    or (section_id = 2 and r <= 1)
    or (section_id = 3 and r <= 1);
```

Comment: Good one, what if my section id has multiple groups e.g 100 sections?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny   If they are in a table, then edit your question to include that info.  If they are not in a table, then add 97 more lines to the WHERE.